# Dynamically get the total amount in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is easy question.
How can I compute the total amount of 2 cells dynamically, Because for now my formula is static only.

[image: First Image]

But I need it dynamically, Because as you can see in the first image the the Range to compute the sum is blank value, Sometimes the value is in K43 and L43 sometimes not.

How can I compute the value dynamically?

This is my formula, Static formula.

[image: Formula]

Yes, I can do it using macro, But as much as I can, I don't want to use macro. Please give me some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: is the formula always two rows down from the values?

Comment: Have you looked in to perhaps `SUMIF()`/`SUMIFS()`?

Comment: @ScottCraner No.

Comment: @BruceWayne I will check on this thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=SUM(INDEX(K:L,MATCH("Grand Total",I:I,0),0))
```

This assumes "Grand Total" is in column `I`.  If not change the `I:I` to the correct column.

Comment: It's actually column `H`, I tried it but I'm getting `#Ref!`

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

If the location of the data that you need to `SUM` moves around, you can use formulas `MATCH` and `ADDRESS` to find the address of the data.

If, as @scott-craner asked, the formula is always two rows down from the data, `OFFSET` would be really useful.

Once you have the address of the cell that your data is located in, you can reference the cell using `INDIRECT`.

[This site](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Address,_Indirect,_Offset,_Index) gives helpful examples and descriptions of how you can use them.

Comment: I'm getting a null value using this formula `=ADDRESS(MATCH("Grand Total",H11:L43,),10)`, I've used the `Grand Total` as lookup value.